# Customize X axis label in D3 grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3 and I tried building a grouped bar chart using D3.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="grouped-chart"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      const data = [
        {
          category: {
            model: 'Model1',
            titleText1: 'T1',
            titleText2: 'T2'
            
          },
          field1: '1000',
          field2: '2000',
        },
        {
          category: {
            model: 'Model2',
            titleText1: 'T3',
            titleText2: 'T4'
          },
          field1: '2000',
          field2: '3000',
        }
      ];
    const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60 };
    const width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right;
    const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    const svg = d3
    .select('#grouped-chart')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .style('background', '#fff');
    const g = svg
    .append('g')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
    const x0 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).paddingInner(0.1);

    const x1 = d3.scaleBand().padding(0.05);

    const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

    const z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#004c6d', '#255e7e', '#3d708f']);
    const keys = Object.keys(data[0]).slice(1);
    x0.domain(data.map((d) => d.category.model));
    x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
    y.domain([0, 4000]);

    g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

    g.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis')
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, 's'));

    g.append('g')
     .selectAll('g')
     .data(data)
     .enter()
     .append('g')
     .attr('transform', (d) => 'translate(' + x0(d.category.model) + ',0)')
     .selectAll('rect')
     .data((d) =>
     keys.map((key) => {
       return { key: key, value: d[key] };
     })
     )
     .enter()
     .append('rect')
     .attr('x', (d) => x1(d.key))
     .attr('y', (d) => y(d.value))
     .attr('width', x1.bandwidth())
     .attr('height', (d) => height - y(d.value))
     .attr('fill', (d) => z(d.key));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the graph, there's Model1 and Model2 labels on the X axis.

Is it possible to have the X axis labels between the ticks as, aligned to the center, an image with text aligned horizontal to the image in 2 lines - Model1, T1. Also, an image below the first image with a single line of horizontally aligned text.

[image: X axis label at each tick]

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you perhaps put a pic of what you are looking for?

Comment: I have added an image of how labels should be at each ticks.